# Seeing the whole financial chart

Tags: plotting

I display a financial chart which I display with `InteractiveTradingChart[]`. My problem is that when my financial is displayed, even though I ask for 6 months of data, the chart only shows a subset of that. I can go to the bottom of the chart and enlarge the area of interest manually. How do I tell `InteractiveTradingChart[]` to display the whole time period I requested?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I wonder, would you post the exact code that you did use? It may be easier that way to diagnose the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Henrick, may I encourage you to register? It would be more convenient for you and for us to keep track and answer your questions if you register for a Stack Exchange account.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

My initial answer seems to have missed the point, which was about how to call up `InteractiveTradingChart[]` with its controls initialized to some values other than defaults.

Someone more able than *moi* may want to examine the output from

```
InteractiveTradingChart[{"GOOG", {{2009, 1, 1}, {2009, 12, 31}}}]
FullGraphics[%] // InputForm
```

and determine whether variables such as `plotrangemin` can be set by the programmer.

---

The date range you specify in the command sets the full time period you work with. The actual display is handled by the buttons and slider at the button of the chart.  If you click on the Max setter button, the whole period will be displayed.  If you click on the month button, one month will be displayed.  You may move to other months (than the one currently being displayed) by using the Slider.  Same respective behavior for Week.

By default, the chart does not display the full time period but rather only a part of it.

[image: chart]

Comment: I think he wants to know if there's a way for `InteractiveTradingStart` to effectively have the Max button clicked by default.

Comment: I looked at the code from InputForm[FullGraphics[%]] and found it impenetrable. I think @Mike Honeychurch might be able to help out with this.

Comment: If his question is how to have the Max button activated by default I do not know the answer. This function is severely under-documented given what it can apparently do.

Comment: I would be up for spelunking but I don't have this function. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I emailed you the code.